# How to use a custom post type as front page?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, query, loop

I would like to set a site's front page to be a single post from a custom post type. I have been able to alter the request for my front page to a Custom Post Type *archive* with the following code (originally [posted here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30851/how-to-use-a-custom-post-type-archive-as-front-page/30854#30854)):

```
function custom_front_page($wp_query){
    if($wp_query->get('page_id')==get_option('page_on_front')){
        $wp_query->set('post_type','album');
        $wp_query->set('page_id',''); // empty
        // fix conditional functions
        $wp_query->is_page = false;
        $wp_query->is_archive = true;
        $wp_query->is_post_type_archive = true;
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','custom_front_page');
```

Replacing

```
$wp_query->is_archive = true;
$wp_query->is_post_type_archive = true;
```

with

```
$wp_query->is_single = true;
```

calls the `single-album.php` template as I'd like to, but it still returns ALL the posts in the "Albums" category, instead of only one.

Adding

```
$wp_query->set('posts_per_page',1);
```

has no effect.

What should I be doing instead?

*Bonus question: is there a good reference somewhere about how to manipulate the `query` this way?*

Comment: [Related Q/A](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18013/how-do-you-use-a-cpt-as-the-default-home-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to display single post on front page would be:

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 'p' => 'POST ID HERE' ) );
include( 'single-POSTTYPE.php' );
```

Answer (score 4):

I had to do the same for a customer and I have found two resources which helped me:

[How do you use a CPT as the default home page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18013/how-do-you-use-a-cpt-as-the-default-home-page)

[http://wpquestions.com/question/show/id/2944](http://web.archive.org/web/20131016145953/http://wpquestions.com/question/show/id/2944)

Comment: Answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). They should actually be an answer instead of a route where someone will _maybe find_ an answer. Please help preventing link rot, [edit] your answer and provide the needed information that helps the OP as well as later visitors to solve their problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
function add_<MYTPE>_to_dropdown( $pages, $r )
{
    if('page_on_front' == $r['name'])
    {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => '<MYTYPE>'
        );
        $items = get_posts($args);
        $pages = array_merge($pages, $items);
    }

    return $pages;
}
add_filter( 'get_pages', 'add_<MYTPE>_to_dropdown' );

function enable_front_page_<MYTPE>( $query )
{
    if('' == $query->query_vars['post_type'] && 0 != $query->query_vars['page_id'])
        $query->query_vars['post_type'] = array( 'page', '<MYTPE>' );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'enable_front_page_<MYTPE>' );
```

Just replace `<MYTYPE>` with your custom post type machine name

Comment: That doesn't work anymore. You need to get rid of this second argument `$r`. Better use Matthew's answer: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/126271/30597

Answer (score 2):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/mpress-custom-front-page/ seems to be implementing the correct logic in a clean manner.

Github https://github.com/wpscholar/mpress-custom-front-page/