# Selecting a post in Dashboard

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, wp-admin

How to make in the admin's dashboard a <select> with the list of all posts of specified post type?

I need this in order to save a post ID with `set_option()` call.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`wp_dropdown_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages) to create the drop down. It accepts an `post_type` parameter.

To avoid collisions with plugins filtering this function you may use `walk_page_dropdown_tree()` and build your own `select`. See [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/18015/73) for a code example.

Comment: It does not work because get_posts(array('post_type'=>'department')) returns nothing (despite of the fact that a post of the type 'department' exists.