# Using single.php from plugin folder instead of default template folder

Tags: posts, pages, single, customization

I am trying to figure out how to use another single.php for a custom plugin I'm making. It's for a custom post type.

Because if people install this plugin, they won't have the custom single-product.php in their theme folder. That's why I want it to be in the plugin folder.

Is there a way to change the path of this custom post type's single.php or a way to automatically generate the file in the theme folder after installing this plugin?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think a hook into `template_include` like [described here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55763/is-it-possible-to-define-a-template-for-a-custom-post-type-within-a-plugin-indep) could be a proper way to do this.

Code could be like this:

```
add_filter('template_include', 'my_plugin_templates');
function my_plugin_templates( $template ) {
    $post_types = array('post');

    if (is_singular($post_types)) {
        $template = 'path/to/singular/template/in/plugin/folder.php';
    }

    return $template;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works! Is there also a way to specify a custom stylesheet for this? The stylesheet I imported in my plugin.php doesn't load up there.

Comment: Puh, never done this, but you should be able to load stylesheets just for your plugin, [see here.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136655/wp-enqueue-style-for-plugin-with-multiple-stylesheets)

Answer (score 1):

Plugins should never* have any visual effect which is not a widget or a shortcode. If you feel the need to manipulate the theme files then you are most likely doing it wrong.

*there are always exceptions as targeting a specific theme or doing something which is so theme agnostic (like popup/lightbox) that there is very little chance of breaking the theme or getting an ugly result.

### EDIT from COMMENTS

This is a border line issue without any white/black type of answer. From what you describe you should have done a theme and not a plugin, but I get you were given the assignment. The right way is like with woocommerce - shortcodes and widgets that display the content managed as CPT otherwise you are more likely not to play nice with all the themes

Comment: I am making a project for school. In this project I am creating a "products" plugin. For this plugin I"m using custom post types. The way this post should look like has to be styled right? What would be a better way to style it then? I also added a gallery to this custom post type. Now need to figure out how to style this gallery and make it nice with jquery

Comment: This is a border line issue without any white/black type of answer. From what you describe you should have done a theme and not a plugin, but I get you were given the assignment. The right way is like with woocommerce - shortcodes and widgets that display the content managed as CPT otherwise you are more likely not to play nice with all the themes.

Answer (score 1):

Where `get_custom_post_type_template` is the function WordPress should call when the content is being retrieved. Note that the filter function the plugin defines must return the a full path to a template file or the resulting page will be blank. The template file should have the same entries as the `single.php` file has in the theme. [For more information visit the site.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template)

```
 <?php
    function get_custom_post_type_template($single_template) {
    global $post;

       if ($post->post_type == 'my_post_type') {
          $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/post-type-template.php';
       }
    return $single_template;
    }
    add_filter( 'single_template', 'get_custom_post_type_template' );
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit in addtion to posting the code, thanks