# Static front page has page url not site url

Tags: custom-post-types, frontpage, customization

I have a custom post type being used as a static page. My site url redirects to `www.mysite.com/slug/my-page-title` but I want it to stay `www.mysite.com`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use a CPT as the default home page?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18013/how-do-you-use-a-cpt-as-the-default-home-page)

Answer (score 0):

In the Settings Menu
Click on Reading

From there you can see "front page displays" and Latest  Posts is ticked

Tick the " a static page" and from the  drop down menu for home select your custom static page and save it.

Now you can see the URL is changed.

Comment: That's what I've done.

Comment: This works for pages, but I added custom a `custom post type` to that drop down. Selecting it causes the wrong url.

Comment: found my answer in the update here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18013/how-do-you-use-a-cpt-as-the-default-home-page#18070