# Wordpress custom post type as homepage with homepage url

Tags: custom-post-types, homepage

I was able to set a custom post type as the homepage for a woocommerce site I am building.

The problem is that when I do this, the homepage url does not display. (i.e. https://mywebsite.com).

Instead it displays as (https://mywebsite.com/post-type/post-name).

Using filters I was able to get rid of the post slug, but the name is still now present when set to the homepage.  If I go to (https://mywebsite.com) the url bar displays (https://mywebsite.com/post-name).

Does anyone know how I can get rid of post-name in the URL when setting this as the homepage?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you use a CPT as the default home page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18013/how-do-you-use-a-cpt-as-the-default-home-page)

Comment: You can find the answer to this question here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/18070/16

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you either need to set your index.php to display your hooks for that post type. Or you need to change your home page setup in the customizer. Here is a link on how to do that.

https://wordpress.com/support/pages/front-page/